# Francis's algorithm - what exactly are the steps that are happening?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms

So I was reading [this link](http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/watkins/pdfiles/francis.pdf)

And [the slides that go with it](http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/watkins/slides/ilas10.pdf)

(sorry for the bad formatting, I don't know how to make it mathlike)

Am I right in thinking that the step

[image: p(A)e1]

for m=2 means that this step is essentially calculating the first column of

[image: A-p1I*A-p2I]

?

I'm still not too sure what e1 means. Is it just a notation for "first column" or is the result of the matrix multiplication supposed to be multiplied by some vector?

Comment: Usually $e_1$ is the first basis vector, i.e. $(e_1)_1=1$ and $(e_1)_i=0$ for $i>1$. As it happens $Ae_1$ is the first column of $A$ (when $A$ is a matrix representing a linear transformation in the standard basis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it simply means you have to multiply the matrix $p(A)$ with the first standardvector $e_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\0\\ \vdots \\ 0  \end{pmatrix}$.